# Insert Button under ScrollView

Tags: android, appcelerator

I'm building an app with appcelerator.

Now I'm build this View.
This is the code:

```
<Alloy>
    <ScrollView width="100%" height="80%" 
            showVerticalScrollIndicator="true">
        <View class="container"  width="100%" height="1600">
            <View class="row">
                <Label id="labelRegistry" class="label" width="25%"></Label>
                <Switch id="checkbox" value="true"></Switch>    
            </View>

            <View class="row">
                <Label id="labelNote" class="label" width="25%"></Label>    
                <TextArea hintText="insert note" width="70%" id="textNote"></TextArea>
            </View>

            <View class="row" >
                <Label id="labelPhoneNumber" width="20%" class="label" top="0px"></Label>       
                <Button id="button" onClick="addButton" top="0px"></Button> 

                <TableView id="tableContact" width="75%" height="auto" 
                    onClick="deleteRow">            
                    <TableViewSection id="tableContact" >                
                    </TableViewSection>
                </TableView>

            </View>

            <View class="row" height="auto" width="100%">
                <TableView id="table" class="table" width="100%">
                    <TableViewSection id="table" >

                    </TableViewSection>
                </TableView>
            </View>

        </View>
    </ScrollView>

<View class="container"  width="100%" height="1600">
        <View id="edit_registry_button" onClick="onSave" height="20%" >
            <ImageView id="edit_registry_icon" image="/images/new_icons/edit_icon_white.png" class="button_icon"></ImageView>
            <Label id="edit_registry_label" class="button_label" text="Salva"></Label>
        </View>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

As you can see, I have a ScrollView with height=80%, under this, I want to have another view with Button. But if I try to run my application, I can see only the scrollview.

Comment: what does `height=1600` mean in this <View class="container"  width="100%" height="1600">?

Comment: Should the container view for button, be put into another `Scrollview` or other `layout`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<Alloy>
    <ScrollView width="100%" height="80%" showVerticalScrollIndicator="true" top="0">
        <View class="container" width="100%" height="100%">
            <View class="row">
                <Label id="labelRegistry" class="label" width="25%"></Label>
                <Switch id="checkbox" value="true"></Switch>
            </View>

            <View class="row">
                <Label id="labelNote" class="label" width="25%"></Label>
                <TextArea hintText="insert note" width="70%" id="textNote"></TextArea>
            </View>

            <View class="row">
                <Label id="labelPhoneNumber" width="20%" class="label" top="0px"></Label>
                <Button id="button" onClick="addButton" top="0px"></Button>

                <TableView id="tableContact" width="75%" height="auto" onClick="deleteRow">
                    <TableViewSection id="tableContact"></TableViewSection>
                </TableView>
            </View>

            <View class="row" height="auto" width="100%">
                <TableView id="table" class="table" width="100%">
                    <TableViewSection id="table"></TableViewSection>
                </TableView>
            </View>

        </View>
    </ScrollView>

    <View class="container" width="100%" height="20%" bottom="0">
        <View id="edit_registry_button" onClick="onSave" height="100%">
            <ImageView id="edit_registry_icon" image="/images/new_icons/edit_icon_white.png" class="button_icon"></ImageView>
            <Label id="edit_registry_label" class="button_label" text="Salva"></Label>
        </View>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

I've added `top:0` to the scrollview and `bottom:0`, `height:20%` to the bottom view.

Also if you don't need the first `<View class="container" width="100%" height="100%">` for styling you can remove this and set the Scrollview to `layout:vertical`